# Getting R textual output into Mathematica

Tags: rlink

I use Mathematica with R because I am able to keep my code and output organized with the notebook interface. Although I can get R structures into *Mathematica* using REvaluate, I can't figure out how to get textual output, from say:

```
summary(fit)
```

Perhaps this can be done by redirecting output to a temporary file, like the case of plots, but I wonder if there is a native solution.

Comment: I'm getting close with REvaluate["capture.output(summary(airquality))"] // TableForm

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I also suggested, without seeing your comment. Took me a while already while answering since SE image upload is somehow broken for me - I was trying (unsuccessfully) to insert the image of the output for a good 20 minutes.

Comment: Well, it finally worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
```

and now

```
StringJoin@Riffle[#, "\n"] &@
  REvaluate["{
     data(iris)
     reg <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris )
     summary.text <- capture.output(print( summary(reg)) )
  }"]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed it was a duplicate.  Sorry about that.  Perhaps it would be useful to have an REvaluate-like function which produces text by default.  Here's why:  it seems that in some cases it's best to just evaluate a number of R inputs without transferring anything at all to Mathematica.  When I have something that I want to use in Mma, only then I can transfer it explicitly.  Another difficulty I had was that it seems difficult to prevent REvaluate from returning any output at all and translating complex and large output (which I don't need anyway) can take a long time.

Comment: @Szabolcs Re: suppressing transfer - place a semicolon at the end of the string R code, and that will do it (it is covered in the docs). Re: function - indeed, agree. What I was thinking of doing was to implement R object references (so far using closure-based emulation) as a full-fledged R data type, using the type-extension mechanism. Then, I could use some meta-programming to write a Mathematica-based "RSummary" function, so that, when it is wrapped around `REvaluate`, we automatically get the summary rather than the imported object. This is quite possible and actually not hard.

Comment: @Szabolcs Re: transfer suppression - see [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html), section *Executing R Code and Getting Data from R*.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This is incredibly helpful, thank you. Do you have a bare bones RSummary that we could start working with?

Comment: @pjc42 Do you mean to generalize the above to wrap around an arbitrary piece of R code?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Leonid, yes exactly. In some cases I just want to run the analysis in R and view the results without necessarily having the data in Mathematica. I had been considering spending time working on pulling apart general RObject[] results and putting in Mathematica tables but your suggestion here is very fit for purpose in a lot of cases. Also, many thanks for RLink, a brilliant addition to what you can do with Mathematica.

Comment: @pjc42 Re: RLink - thanks, it's good to know that it is useful. Re: summary - you can then simply do something like `RSummary[rcode_String] :=StringJoin@Riffle[#, "\n"] &@REvaluate["capture.output(print( summary(" <> rcode <> ")) )"]`. You can call it like `RSummary["reg"]` (from the above example), where in place of `"reg"` you can use a variable or just a piece of code which evaluates to some R expression, for which you want the summary.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Works great, thanks. On a separate note, do you know if there is a work around for Windows "RHomeLocation" limitation to 2.xx or less (i.e. no 3.x)?

Comment: @pjc42 There isn't. I was requested to deal with this problem by a number of people, but didn't have a chance to do it yet. But it is one of the top things on my RLink todo list (perhaps the first one).