# Installing R packages using RLink on Mac OS X

Tags: packages, rlink

Is there any updates regarding installing CRAN packages via RLink in Mathematica 10 on Mac OS X? Or are we still stuck with the base R package and that's it?

I was able to point to my R distribution using this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43731/installr-on-os-x-with-external-r-installation) but using external packages led to errors.

Here is my code:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
SetEnvironment[
"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> 
"/Library/Frameworks/R.Framework/Resources/lib"];

InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> 
"/Library/Frameworks/R.Framework/Resources"];

REvaluate["R.version.string"]

REvaluate["library(GA)"]

REvaluate["f <- function(x)  abs(x)+cos(x)
           fitness <- function(x) -f(x)
           ga(type='real-valued',fitness=fitness,min=-20,max=20)
           summary(GA)"]

Out[15]= $Failed
```

and the error message:

```
REvaluate::rerr: Failed to retrieve the value for variable or piece of code f<- function(x)  abs(x)+cos(x)
fitness <- function(x) -f(x)
ga(type='real-valued',fitness=fitness,min=-5,max=5)
summary(GA). The following R error was encountered: Error in typeof(myRandomVar123456740025) : 
object 'myRandomVar123456740025' not found >>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an external R, as described in the answer you link to, and you can install packages into this external R installation.  The errors you see are not related to this.

Here are the problems with the code:

1. `REvaluate` needs to be used with a single R expression.  It's not possible to pass it multiple expressions.  Enclose everything in `{ ... }` to make it into a single expression.

   ```
   REvaluate["x <- 1; x+x"]  (* <-- INVALID *)
   REvaluate["{ x <- 1; x+x }"]  (* <-- good *)
   ```
2. You were trying to evaluate `summary(GA)`.  There's no variable named `GA`.
3. `REvaluate` returns the result of the evaluation as a Mathematica expression.  It does not return the output that R would *print*.  While using `summary(something)` as the last line of your input is not incorrect, it's probably not what you were looking for here.  Please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15498/12).  You can use `REvaluate["capture.output(summary(x))"]` to see what R would print.
4. This works:

   ```
   REvaluate["
    {f <- function(x)  abs(x)+cos(x);
     fitness <- function(x) -f(x);
     x <- ga(type='real-valued',fitness=fitness,min=-20,max=20);
     summary(x)}"]
   ```

   You might want to add `caputre.output` as in point 3. though.
5. RLink has trouble transferring objects of class `"ga"`.  This is why

   ```
   REvaluate["x <- ga(type='real-valued',fitness=fitness,min=-20,max=20)"]
   ```

   will give an error.  The situation is not dissimilar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22942/12).

   Workaround:

   Use a semicolon to prevent RLink from trying to translate this object to a Mathematica expression.  You probably wouldn't be able to use it in any other way than passing it back to an R function, anyway.  So let's just store the result in `x` but no return it to Mathematica:

   ```
   REvaluate["x <- ga(type='real-valued',fitness=fitness,min=-20,max=20);"]
   ```

   What one *would* use in Mathematica is data extracted from the `"ga"` object, e.g.

   ```
   REvaluate["x@population"]
   ```