# Parsing RLink RObject for aovlist and other object types

Tags: probability-or-statistics, rlink

There are some slightly similar requests out there (e.g. [Getting R textual output into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15498/getting-r-textual-output-into-mathematica) ) but I'm wondering if anyone has put together a more general purpose solution to parsing `RObject[]` results, especially in the case of the `"class" :> {"summary.aovlist"}` or, even better `"class" :> {"aovlist", "listof"}` variety.

Since Mathematica still doesn't have a complete mixed-effects implementation for the linear model or anova, I am forced to use R for a lot of my analysis. Usually I just do an `Export[]` a CSV, send shell command out to run an R script, etc.

I am trying to do it all via `RLink[]` now, since I prefer staying in *MMa* as much as possible.

One thing I like about the current `RLink` implementation  is that there is a 'known' `TableForm` for the `data.frame()` object... so you can say

```
mydf = REvaluate["{
 df = data.frame(s=ss, level=levels, phase=phases, dp=dps)
 as.data.frame(df)
}"];

mydf//TableForm
```

and get nice output, like

```
    s   level   phase        dp
1   1   Novice  Approach    -0.896723
2   1   Novice  Capture      0.967293
...
```

I'd think it'd be nice to be able to to a `TableForm[summaryTableFromRaov]` and get pretty output.`capture.output()` from R works OK, but being able to mess with the `RObject` within *Mathematica* itself seems like a better way to go.

As requested, here's a simple example-

```
RSet["ss",{"s1","s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2","s2"}];
RSet["rt",{80,80,90,91,100,103,122,154}];
RSet["cond",{"vis","vis","hap","hap","vis","vis","hap","hap"}];

df=REvaluate["{
    df = data.frame(ss=ss,rt=rt,cond=cond)
    as.data.frame(df)
}"];

TableForm[df]
    ss  rt  cond
1   s1  80  vis
2   s1  80  vis
3   s2  90  hap
4   s2  91  hap
5   s1  100 vis
6   s1  103 vis
7   s2  122 hap
8   s2  154 hap

anova=REvaluate["aox=aov(rt~cond+Error(ss/cond), df)"];
```

Now, in a perfect world we'd get something pleasant out of we did

```
TableForm[anova]
```

but this just dumps the `RObject`.

We can do `REvaluate["capture.output(aox)"] // TableForm` and get a *text* output of the `aov` that we can then 'table-ize'

```
Call:
aov(formula = rt ~ cond + Error(ss/cond), data = df)

Grand Mean: 102.5

Stratum 1: ss

Terms:
                  cond
Sum of Squares  1104.5
Deg. of Freedom      1

...
```

but now we lose the object itself and just get a text version of the anova table.

I'm thinking that it would be nice to keep the structure of the R object but be able to pretty-print the summary table, etc via `TableForm` and friends. Even better, it would be nice to be able to parse the various attributes *out of the object* like one can with the other statistics functions, like for example the `HypothesisTestData[]` objects that one can query for properties.

In the above case, one could write something that 'understands' an R

```
REvaluate["class(aox)"]
{aovlist,listof}
```

`aovlist` object... or other objects like `lm`, `mer`, `lme4` objects in the case that I'm interested. It seems like I need extensions that understands the structure of specific `RObject` types beyond, say, `data.frame`s.

Comment: Some concrete minimal example would be helpful, with the comments of what you are currently getting and what you'd like to be getting.